# How to access users google calendar information using google calendar api without oauth?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am developing a chat application to provide information on users in our organization.

My question is there any way to access someone's calendar without their inference?
if there is a way how to do it?

Comment: It depends. Is it a public Calendar? Are you a G Suite admin? Do you want to invite or to create events on the other Calendar?

Comment: @Jescanellas its public and I am not G suite admin

Comment: I see. And will the users give edit permissions to you? Otherwise it's not possible

Comment: @Jescanellas thank for replaying now my doubt clarified

Answer (score 0):

Writing it as an answer so it's more clear. In case of public Calendars, you still need the owner to give edit permissions to you in order to make changes in the Calendar, like creating events.

For a more complete explanation: [Share your calendar with someone](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en)